# How do I get the Swallow potion in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am attempting to complete the "On Death's Bed" quest, and need to create the Swallow potion. However, I don't *have* that potion receipe listed in my Alchemy screen. I only have two formulas - Tawnty Owl and Thunderbolt.

This shows my available potions (with all the filters enabled).

[image: My filters]

How do I get the Swallow potion when I'm already several hours into the game (I've beaten the griffin in White Orchard)?

I have already seen [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220943/missing-swallow-and-full-moon-potion-diagrams) question, but it doesn't seem to answer my problem. It says that I should already have it.

When talking when the herbalist again, the only options I've given are the check what herbs she's selling, find out her story or leave.

Comment: Potions you've already created aren't listed on the Alchemy screen, I believe. Maybe you've actually created it? Try meditating (with strong alcohol in your inventory), and see if you then have some?

Comment: @BryanPendleton, my screenshot shows the potions that I've already created.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. My old eyes weren't quite good enough to see that, but I see it now.

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me. I had to just play through the game until I got the Swallow recipe (I don't remember where I found it) and then I went back to White Orchard to continue this quest.

Answer (score 5):

Check the "already crafted" under filters to see swallow under the alchemy tab again

Comment: This is a life saver, for some reason the "Already Crafted" option was checked out by default under the filters

Answer (score 3):

This is really strange. Swallow is a starting recipe, I can confirm this from my personal experience as well as from the information on other sites.

[Witcher 3 wiki](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Swallow)

> Swallow is a potion in The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt. Geralt of Rivia has the ability to brew this potion from the moment he reaches White Orchard

[IGN guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/Swallow)

Looks like quite a severe bug to me.

The best workaround would be to cheat.

1. Get the [Console enabler](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher3/mods/1555/?)
2. Follow the instructions on how to use it.
3. The code **additem(Swallow 1)** should add the basic Swallow to your inventory.

As an aside. Could you try starting a new game and check whether the recipe is missing again, once you reach White Orchard?

Comment: I just went through a new game to test this and I got Cat, Swallow and White Honey at the start.

Comment: For me, it was a filter on the ps4 version. See Maremaldor's answer below.

Comment: `additem(Swallow 1)` didnt work for me (syntax should be `additem('item', count)` as [seen here](https://github.com/gamebooster/witcher3-booster/blob/master/README.md))

I fixed it in my game with `addrecipespotions` and `addrecipespotions2`

Answer (score 3):

All of the alchemy items in your inventory replenish with meditation +  1 alcohol item. It's like recharging a battery.

If you don't have alcohol items, you can drop the empty potion vial that's in your inventory and the potion recipe will show up again under alchemy.

Comment: It took two years for the correct answer to be posted, and two _more_ years later it's still at the bottom.  +1!

Answer (score 0):

actually, if you craft any type of potion it makes 3 of it, it therefore will not allow you to make more until youve used up those 3. swallow wouldnt show up for me, but thats because i had 3 sitting in my inventory, same with thunderbolt

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I discovered that as long as you have the empty swollow potion bottle in your inventory you cant brew a new swollow potion, so in order no brew a new one you have to drop the empty bottle.
Its the same for every potion!
Hope this helps!